# servicio que modifica el archivo host en c#

Tags: c#, windows, servicio

es para ver si me podrian ayudar, es que he creado un servicio de windows que debería modificar el archivos host, pero no me funciona, por favor alguien que me ayude la verdad no se en que estoy fallando.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Net;

namespace PeerfyService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private double servicePollInterval;
              public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            //providing the time in miliseconds 
            timer.Interval = servicePollInterval;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Reply = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://admin.appguardian.co/peerfy/hosts");
            string google = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
            File.WriteAllText(google, Reply);

        }



        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            base.OnContinue();
            timer.Start();
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            timer.Stop();
        }

        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            base.OnShutdown();
            timer.Stop();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas posibilidades. Deberías tratar de averiguar si se está produciendo un error y cual.

Puedes mirar en el visor de eventos de la máquina en la que se está ejecutando el servicio para ver si se está registrando algún error. También podrías introducir trazas para poder ver dónde se produce el problema.

Otra opción es depurar el servicio, aunque no es tan simple como con una aplicación de escritorio se puede hacer:
[How to: Debug Windows Service Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Asegúrate de que el usuario con el que se ejecuta el servicio (puedes verlo en la configuración de arranque del servicio) tiene permisos para acceder y sobrescribir el fichero `hosts` y para acceder a internet para descargar el fichero.

Por otra parte veo que nunca inicializas la variable `servicePollInterval` por lo que siempre tendrá un valor 0, valor que no es válido para la propiedad `Interval` del `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no explicas con exactitud lo que haces, `File.WriteAllText(path, text)`  espera una ruta de un archivo pero le estas enviando una ruta de un directorio.

```
string Reply = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://admin.appguardian.co/peerfy/hosts");
string google = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";

// invalido, google contiene la ruta de un directorio, no un archivo!
File.WriteAllText(google, Reply);
```

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` es un directorio, no un archivo. Si es que tienes un archivo llamado `host`, entonces tienes que especificarle la extension del mismo. Por ejemplo `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt`.

Si `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` es un directorio, entonces tienes que especificarle a que archivo va a escribir, como por ejemplo: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts\datos.txt`.

Comment: `hosts` es un archivo que utiliza Windows para guardar correspondencias entre nombres de dominio y direcciones IP. No tiene extensión y suele estar ubicado en la carpeta `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`